# Display an object as Gson in Android studio logcat

Tags: android-studio, gson

I get Gson object from API, and want to see either am I receiving the right list of items. When display it in logcat, it is too difficult to read. Is it possible to apply any formatter as in google chrome?

Comment: If you want to properly format JSON-data use a json [beautifier](https://jsonformatter.org/).

Comment: You can also stringify json data and then print it in logcat.

Comment: make .json file in visual code or another IDE and read the file , it's easy to read